# What does => mean in a Linq Expression

Tags: c#, linq

*Although this is a duplicate question, I had never seen the expression "=>" in code before. If I had known this was specifically a lambda expression, I would have google'd and figured it out on my own. Thanks!

I'm new to using Linq, so the use of "=>" really confused me when I ran across it in this code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public static class Extend
{
    public static double StandardDeviation(this IEnumerable<double> values)
    {
        double avg = values.Average();
        return Math.Sqrt(values.Average(v=>Math.Pow(v-avg,2)));
    }
}
```

Source: [Standard deviation of generic list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141692/standard-deviation-of-generic-list)

A few questions:
What does => do here?
Intellisense tells me that 'v' is an int, but it was never declared. How does this work?

Comment: Google lambda's in .NET. Its a big subject, but you can easily read up on it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This notation `=>` means lambda expression

example:

```
Enumerable.Range(0,100).Where(x=>x==1);
```

here `x=> x==1` is a anonymous delegate accepting `int` as a parameter and returning `bool`. It is:

```
delegate bool SomeDelegate(int x);
```

and you can assign body of your delegate to:

```
bool Function(int x)
{ 
   return x==1;
}
```

> A lambda expression is an anonymous function that you can use to
>   create delegates or expression tree types. By using lambda
>   expressions, you can write local functions that can be passed as
>   arguments or returned as the value of function calls. Lambda
>   expressions are particularly helpful for writing LINQ query
>   expressions.
>
> To create a lambda expression, you specify input parameters (if any)
>   on the left side of the lambda operator =>, and you put the expression
>   or statement block on the other side. For example, the lambda
>   expression x => x * x specifies a parameter that’s named x and returns
>   the value of x squared. You can assign this expression to a delegate
>   type, as the following example shows:

source:
[Read about lambda expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397687.aspx)

Here is a SO question about why to use lambdas: [C# Lambda expressions: Why should I use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167343/c-sharp-lambda-expression-why-should-i-use-this)

Comment: I can't believe a straight up copy-paste from wikipedia got that many upvotes. Also the question was quite easily Googlable and should be closed

Comment: @TonyTheLion 1. It's not wikipedia 2. I was prepairing suitable example, which can be found now in my answer

Comment: The => operator can be used in two ways in C#:

As the lambda operator in a lambda expression, it separates the input variables from the lambda body.

In an expression body definition, it separates a member name from the member implementation.

Answer (score 6):

the operator `=>` has nothing to do with linq - it's a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397687.aspx). It's used to create anonymous functions, so you don't need to create a full function for every small thing.

so the expression:

```
s => s + 5
```

could be translated to:

```
int fun(int s)
{
return s + 5;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`=>` is the notation for a [Lamdba expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397687.aspx), that is basically a shothand way of writing an anonymous method :)

It will also automatically infer types where it can, so that is why v is never declared as an int, but is understood by the compiler to be an int anyway.

Comment: this could be a comment not an answer

Comment: I think that's harsh. The problem with => is that it's hard to search for if you don't know it's to do with Lambda expressions

Comment: There is no other answer to this imo. It's either to link to a page about Lambda expressions, or to copy paste a really big article into here? What would you suggest to do instead to answer this?

Comment: Not at all, as it has been answered before.

Comment: @guymid - What is harsh? I didn't intend to sound harsh at all :)

Comment: @ØyvindKnobloch-Bråthen It may be unintended but "You really need to read up on" is implying that OP should already have read up on Lambda... and you don't provide any description of what they are. A brief summary would do. By not including a summary it looks like OP really should know what they are

Comment: @guymid - It was actually unintended. I have edited it to be nicer now (and also more informative). I even added a extremly friendly smiley in there! Happy? ;)

Comment: @ØyvindKnobloch-Bråthen IMHO that's much better :-D

Comment: @guymid - I aim to please he..he

Answer (score 1):

You can also read [this very short article](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/298963/Understand-Lambda-Expressions-in-3-minutes), it is a very good summary of what is a lambda expressions, how to use it and when.

The example given is

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>{11,37,52};
List<int> oddNumbers = numbers.where(n => n % 2 == 1).ToList();
//Now oddNumbers is equal to 11 and 37
```

at line 2, `oddNumbers` is now equal to numbers where `number % 2` is equal to 1, so where number is odd

Answer (score 1):

To better understand this. I would rewrite your code without LINQ as below:

```
public static class Extend
    {
        public static double StandardDeviation(this IEnumerable<double> values)
        {
            double avg = values.Average();
            var newValues = new List<double>();
            foreach (var v in values)
            {
                newValues.Add(Math.Pow(v - avg, 2));
            }

            return Math.Sqrt(newValues.Average());
        }
    }
```

Now you can compare these two versions of code and see the relation.

Answer (score 0):

This is a lambda expression.

Take a look to this article : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397687.aspx

Take "v" as an element of the list (so the type is depending of the list), and "=>" indicate the action to do with this element (Math.Pow() is the action).